# Comparison of references

Tags: reference, ocaml

When I try to compare two refs their behavior makes me confused, from what I understand when using "r1 = r2" I am comparing the content of two refs, if I do "r1 == r2" I am comparing the address of these two refs. But when I run the following code, r1 and r2 both point to v, but why their address is not the same? How should check if two refs point to the same object?

```
# let r1 = ref v;;
val r1 : int ref = {contents = 1}
# let v = 1;;
val v : int = 1
# let r1 = ref v;;
val r1 : int ref = {contents = 1}
# let r2 = ref v;;
val r2 : int ref = {contents = 1}
# r1 == r2;;
- : bool = false
```

Answer (score 1):

The `==` operator compares the "physical equality" of two values. In practical terms it is indeed the addresses of the values that you are comparing. If you compare two references `r1 == r2` you are comparing the addresses *of the references*, not the addresses that are sitting inside the references. Since `r1` and `r2` are not the same reference, they have different addresses. Hence they don't compare as equal using `==`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but how should I check if two references point to the same object in OCaml?

Comment: To test if two references are referring to the same mutable object: `!ref1 == !ref2`. Note that you should not use `==` for comparing immutable objects. If you give more details of the problem you're trying to solve it would be possible to say more (probably :-).

Answer (score 1):

As a follow-on to Jeffrey's answer, consider what happens if we dereference `v1` and `v2` and compare them for physical equality.

```
# !v1 == !v2;;
- : bool = true
```

But please note that this is a special case for physical equality of `int` values, and will not necessarily hold true for other types of data.

```
# 1.1 == 1.1;;
- : bool = false
# "hello" == "hello";;
- : bool = false
# 43. == 43.;;
- : bool = false
```